# Unable to read GRIB datas with XArray

Tags: grib, grib-2, noaa, xarray

I used this code to read grib data

```py
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

path = "gfsanl_4_2019101000.g2"
os.chdir(path)
ds = xr.open_dataset('gfs_4_20191010_0000_006.grb2', engine='cfgrib')
```

And the output as is follows,

```
DatasetBuildError: multiple values for unique key, try re-open the file with one of:
    filter_by_keys={'typeOfLevel': 'hybrid'}
    filter_by_keys={'typeOfLevel': 'atmosphere'}
    filter_by_keys={'typeOfLevel': 'surface'}
    filter_by_keys={'typeOfLevel': 'unknown'}
    filter_by_keys={'typeOfLevel': 'isobaricInPa'}
    filter_by_keys={'typeOfLevel': 'isobaricInhPa'}
    filter_by_keys={'typeOfLevel': 'meanSea'}
    filter_by_keys={'typeOfLevel': 'depthBelowLandLayer'}
    filter_by_keys={'typeOfLevel': 'heightAboveGround'}
    filter_by_keys={'typeOfLevel': 'nominalTop'}
    filter_by_keys={'typeOfLevel': 'heightAboveGroundLayer'}
    filter_by_keys={'typeOfLevel': 'tropopause'}
    filter_by_keys={'typeOfLevel': 'maxWind'}
    filter_by_keys={'typeOfLevel': 'heightAboveSea'}
    filter_by_keys={'typeOfLevel': 'isothermZero'}
    filter_by_keys={'typeOfLevel': 'pressureFromGroundLayer'}
    filter_by_keys={'typeOfLevel': 'sigmaLayer'}
    filter_by_keys={'typeOfLevel': 'sigma'}
    filter_by_keys={'typeOfLevel': 'potentialVorticity'}
```

I tried to use `filter_by_keys` and `backend_kwargs` arguments to define the keys but I failed. Can you advice any solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

If you add the `backend_kwargs` line, it will work properly,
for example:-

```py
ds = xr.open_dataset('gfs_4_20191010_0000_006.grb2',
                     engine='cfgrib',
                     backend_kwargs={'filter_by_keys': {'typeOfLevel': 'surface'}})
```

You can specify type of level you want to do the analysis specifically, the developers says `cfgrib` and its dependency has issues with handling multiple types of level at the moment. May be in future they will rectify this issue, as `xarray` always did and become an amazing tool.